# Python package that knows how to manipulate config files for various software products

Tags: python, configuration-management

I once ran across a very cool Python project that provides a Pythonic interface to various config file formats like:

- `/etc/hosts`
- `/etc/resolv.conf`
- Samba `smb.conf`

Etc. I think the library was produced by RedHat.

I'm not talking about a full-blown configuration tool like Ansible or SaltStack.

I can't remember the name of this library. Do you?

Answer (score 2):

Found it:

[Augeas - a configuration API](http://augeas.net/)

> Augeas is a configuration editing tool. It parses configuration files in their native formats and transforms them into a tree. Configuration changes are made by manipulating this tree and saving it back into native config files.

It is a C library but provides Python bindings.